# Routing root of a non-default module under a custom domain using dispatch.xml

Tags: google-app-engine

#### Struggling with the incomplete documentation on using the dispatch.xml feature of the default module:

I have the following `dispatch.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch-entries>
    <dispatch>
        <url>www.custom-domain.com/</url>
        <module>default</module>
    </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

The above route works without any problems. I have also omitted sub-domain mappings that are working as well.

#### Here is what I have deployed:

```
gcloud preview app list-versions
11:24 PM Host: appengine.google.com
admin-console: ['2']
default: ['2', ah-builtin-datastoreservice]
```

I want to configure `http://www.custom-domain/admin/*` to point to my `admin-console` module.

I know the module is deployed and working correctly because when I go to `http://admin-console.myappid.appspot.com` it displays the correct `index.html` page.

#### I tried the with adding following stanza [based on the examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing).

```
<dispatch>
    <url>*/admin/*</url>
    <module>admin-console</module>
</dispatch>
```

I saved the file and ran `mvn appengine:update_dispatch` and it reports no errors and that the operation was successful.

When I try and go to `http://www.custom-domain.com/admin/index.html` or any other variation of `http://www.custom-domain/admin/` it fails with a `404 Not Found` message.

I have also tried the following and it fails with `404 Not Found` as well.

```
<dispatch>
    <url>www.comic-pages.com/admin/*</url>
    <module>admin-console</module>
</dispatch>
```

I have searched and searched and can't find a reason this isn't working.

#### What am I missing here that isn't explicitly said in the documentation and examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What I expected it to be doing:

```
<dispatch>
    <url>www.custom-domain.com/admin/*</url>
    <module>admin-console</module>
</dispatch>
```

Routing `www.custom-domain/admin/*` to `/*` of the `admin-console` module.

#### Debugging via logs I hate it!

After digging through the logs for the `default` module and not finding any entries for the `www.custom-domain.com/admin/*` route, I looked at the `admin-console` module and found lots of entries there. *These were about 10 minutes behind wall time.*

I was trying to load the `index.html` from the root context of the `admin-console` module.

```
http://www.custom-domain.com/admin/index.html
```

This was producing the following error in the `admin-console` module log.

```
/admin/index.html No handlers matched this URL.
```

#### What it is actually doing:

What it is actually doing is routing `www.custom-domain.com/admin/*` to `/admin/*` of the `admin-console` module.

I tried adding a directory and moving my `index.html` to `src/main/webapp/admin/index.html`. This doesn't work either, it is actually looking for a handler.

I created a `Servlet` and added a mapping for `<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>` and it started working.

#### If you want to route to the root of a non-default module:

So if you want to map something to the `/` of a non-default module you have to specify a subdomain and map it to the module.

```
<dispatch>
    <url>admin.custom-domain.com/*</url>
    <module>admin-console</module>
</dispatch>
```

This is the only way I have discovered to access anything in the root context of a non-default module.